KustoBlobError When Performing Queued Ingestion with azure-kusto-ingest python client
I am able to successfully ingest data from a local pandas DataFrame into Azure ADX using the python azure-kusto-ingest library when I run this from my windows laptop.
However, when I run this from an Azure compute Windows VM, a KustoBlobError is raised with the following message:

azure.kusto.data.exceptions.KustoBlobError:
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002B73E481EA0>:
Failed to resolve 'j6v{adx_cluster_name}00.blob.core.windows.net'
([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

I am using the same Azure Service Principle (SP) in both environments, and am able to read data from the same ADX table with this SP in both environments prior to performing the ingest, so authentication/authorization should not be a problem.
While I initially had different versions of the python azure libraries installed on the VM compared to the laptop, I've incrementally changed all of these library versions to match what is on my laptop environment, but that has not resolved the issue.
It seems there are two blob storage resources referenced in the logs, with the following name structures:

0uz{adx_cluster_name}01

j6v{adx_cluster_name}00


When I run the code on the VM, it looks like both of these two blob resources are tried with the order being random, and the last one tried is referenced in the error message.
In the client logs, I see this pair of log entries for request/response without an error when run on my laptop:

> 2024-04-17T09:40:15 | INFO | in
> azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy | Request URL:
> 'https://j6v{adx_cluster_name}00.blob.core.windows.net/20240417-ingestdata-e5c334ee145d4b4-0/manufacturing_eng__tag_value__359d382f-3780-4d17-a4b9-e2f81fc97840__df_2020154677360_1713361188_cad099c7-731e-4dac-bbab-8bec9eed1b5d.csv.gz?timeout=REDACTED&sv=REDACTED&st=REDACTED&se=REDACTED&sr=REDACTED&sp=REDACTED&sig=REDACTED'
> Request method: 'PUT' Request headers:
>     'Content-Length': '8844133'
>     'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
>     'If-None-Match': '*'
>     'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
>     'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
>     'Accept': 'application/xml'
>     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.12.0 Python/3.10.0 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
>     'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
>     'x-ms-client-request-id': '05db41cf-fcc0-11ee-85bc-8cae4cf0e805' A body is sent with the request
> 
> 
> 2024-04-17T09:40:16 | INFO | in
> azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy | Response status:
> 201 Response headers:
>     'Content-Length': '0'
>     'Content-MD5': 'REDACTED'
>     'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 17 Apr 2024 13:40:16 GMT'
>     'ETag': '"0x8DC5EE3EA8B33AB"'
>     'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
>     'x-ms-request-id': 'b1aead80-901e-00d8-78cc-905fdd000000'
>     'x-ms-client-request-id': '05db41cf-fcc0-11ee-85bc-8cae4cf0e805'
>     'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
>     'x-ms-content-crc64': 'REDACTED'
>     'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'REDACTED'
>     'Date': 'Wed, 17 Apr 2024 13:40:16 GMT'

Ane when I run it on the VM there are a series of eight (8) log entries for request attempts with no responses and with each of those two blob resources being tried 4 times (showing the last of the series of requests prior to the error):

> 2024-04-16T14:28:22 | INFO | in
> azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy | Request URL:
> 'https://j6v{adx_cluster_name}00.blob.core.windows.net/20240416-ingestdata-e5c334ee145d4b4-0/manufacturing_eng__tag_value__623a8561-2cab-4726-8234-eab384bf2b24__df_2986047233024_1713291932_9f2f2ff2-2a38-4c7d-a6fa-4c43451c3fe1.csv.gz?timeout=REDACTED&sv=REDACTED&st=REDACTED&se=REDACTED&sr=REDACTED&sp=REDACTED&sig=REDACTED'
> Request method: 'PUT' Request headers:
>     'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
>     'Content-Length': '903579'
>     'If-None-Match': '*'
>     'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
>     'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
>     'Accept': 'application/xml'
>     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.12.0 Python/3.10.11 (Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0)'
>     'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
>     'x-ms-client-request-id': '1b5a95a8-fc1f-11ee-8cc7-6045bd7dbb82' No body was attached to the request

Note that for these failed requests, they all indicate that "No body was attached to the request", whereas the successful requests state that "A body is sent with the request".
And then the error trace looks like this:

> 2024-04-16T14:28:23 | ERROR | in root |
> :
> Failed to resolve 'j6v{adx_cluster_name}00.blob.core.windows.net'
> ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\ingest\ingest_client.py",
> line 229, in upload_blob
>     blob_client.upload_blob(data=stream, timeout=timeout)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py",
> line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py",
> line 728, in upload_blob
>     return upload_block_blob(**options)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_upload_helpers.py",
> line 101, in upload_block_blob
>     response = client.upload(   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py",
> line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_generated\operations\_block_blob_operations.py",
> line 793, in upload
>     pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(  # pylint: disable=protected-access   File
> "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 230, in run
>     return first_node.send(pipeline_request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   [Previous line repeated 2 more times]   File
> "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\policies\_redirect.py",
> line 197, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\policies.py",
> line 543, in send
>     raise err   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\policies.py",
> line 517, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\policies.py",
> line 313, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 86, in send
>     response = self.next.send(request)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py",
> line 119, in send
>     self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\base_client.py",
> line 333, in send
>     return self._transport.send(request, **kwargs)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\transport\_requests_basic.py",
> line 386, in send
>     raise error azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: :
> Failed to resolve 'j6v{adx_cluster_name}00.blob.core.windows.net'
> ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "{python_script_path}",
> line 546, in 
>     adx_status_queues.extend(load_data_ADX(kusto_ingest_client, kusto_ingest_config["db"], "tag_value", combinedDF))   File
> "{python_script_path}",
> line 411, in load_data_ADX
>     r = kusto_client.ingest_from_dataframe(data, ingestion_properties=ingestion_props)   File
> "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\ingest\base_ingest_client.py",
> line 121, in ingest_from_dataframe
>     return self.ingest_from_file(temp_file_path, ingestion_properties)   File
> "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py",
> line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\ingest\ingest_client.py",
> line 77, in ingest_from_file
>     blob_descriptor = self.upload_blob(   File "E:\apps\python310\venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\ingest\ingest_client.py",
> line 237, in upload_blob
>     raise KustoBlobError(e) azure.kusto.data.exceptions.KustoBlobError:
> :
> Failed to resolve 'j6v{adx_cluster_name}00.blob.core.windows.net'
> ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

These are the ingestion properties I'm using:
ingestion_props = IngestionProperties(
    database=dest_database_name,
    table=dest_table_name,
    data_format=DataFormat.CSV,
    report_level=ReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses,
    ingestion_mapping_kind=IngestionMappingKind.CSV,
    column_mappings=data_mappings
)

r = kusto_client.ingest_from_dataframe(data, ingestion_properties=ingestion_props)

I think I've seen somewhere in the documentation that for queued ingestion ADX uses temporary blob storage to land the data before actually ingesting it, so I'm assuming these blob storage containers being referenced in the logs correspond to those, but am not certain.
Any ideas what is going on here or how to try to fix it?

This looks like a connectivity issue (the DNS name is not resolved when you run from the cloud). Perhaps you ADX Cluster has a custom network setup (private endpoints or something similar) which makes the service and its staging storage accounts inaccessible from some locations.

Yeah - it does seem like networking is the problem.  The ADX cluster is on a private endpoint.  But why is ADX redirecting my client to connect directly to these blob stores?  This seems like a poor design - once I have established auth with the ADX service, I would think ADX would handle the payload and take care of the temporary persistence and then retrieval for processing as something internal to ADX.  Is there some way to work around this problem that doesn't require my client to also connect directly to the ADX-associated blob stores?  Is there some configuration on the ADX side?
